# Grails Project Suddenly Missing Dependencies

Tags: gradle, grails, dependencies, build.gradle, grails3

I use multiple grails projects for various reporting and API related tasks. Yesterday when trying to build my projects I started getting various errors related to missing dependencies. I made no code changes to prompt these missing dependencies, some of which are coming from other packages that have been in use for years in my projects without ever complaining of these missing dependencies. Here is a sample of some of such errors:

```
C:\Users\Public\Grails3\fitment-app\grails-app\controllers\com\gammapowersports\FitmentProductController.groovy: 11: unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
```

And another:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Failed to introspect class: class grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.JwtService
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Failed to introspect class: class grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.JwtService
at grails.core.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.isArtefact(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:129)
at grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.addOverridableArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:772)
at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.registerProvidedArtefacts(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:310)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.performGrailsInitializationSequence(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:110)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.initializeGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:93)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.setApplicationContext(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:225)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.<init>(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:77)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:69)
at com.gammapowersports.Application.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(Application.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 24 common frames omitted
```

I can solve these errors by adding dependencies to satisfy the dependencies specifically, which I have done to get my projects building again.

My question is why did these dependencies suddenly start failing? I'm wondering if it is related to the migration away from Bintray as the main plugin provider for Grails. Has anyone else experienced these issues?

Answer (score 1):

The most COMMON issue is just that you need to refresh your dependencies. Run this command:

```
./gradlew clean;./gradlew build --stacktrace  --refresh-dependencies
```

This should give clean your cache and refresh your dependencies.

For the record, bintray has said they will continue to maintain all the old repos/archives but they will not acept any new ones.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had tried this originally to no avail. I likely should have mentioned that in my original question.

Comment: if you are still having issues it may be because of the 'spring-security-rest' dependency I am seeing. They DID move this internally (Grails, OCI) and remove from the Grails plugins so you will have to refer to an older copy or something if you want it in your repo. I actually downloaded the lib and have it included as part of my plugin now for future purposes since they no longer provide.